# Why the sum of the product of ideals are defined as finite sums/products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Given a ring $R$ and some index set $I$, why is the sum/product of ideals are defined for finite sums/products?

Sum of ideals $\sum_{i \in I}I_i=\{\sum{x_i}: i \in I \}$

Product of ideals $\prod_{i \in I}I_i=\{\prod{x_i}: i \in I \} $

Comment: you mean product of ideals in a principal ideal domain ? then $(a)(b) = (ab)$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i) = (\prod_{i=1}^n a_i)$

Comment: Because, in an arbitrary ring, infinite sums and products do not make any sense. So, if you have an infinite indexing set $I$, $\sum_{i\in I} I_i$ is defined as the ideal generated by all the possible  sums $\sum x_i$, $x_i\in I_i$ and all but finitely many $x_i$s are zero.

Comment: @user1952009, my ring $R$ is an arbitrary ring, I do not know whether it is a PID or not.

Comment: @Mohan, are infinite sums/products not defined? Does anything change when I have a countably infinite index set?

Comment: Unless you have some topology, infinite sums of elements can not make sense, like for example real numbers.