# on the product of any two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

i was reading an Algebra textbook by Siegfried Bosch and I read that given two ideals $\mathfrak a $ and $\mathfrak b$ of a certain ring $R$;we can construct a new ideal $\mathfrak a$•$\mathfrak b $ ={$\sum_{i=1}^{<\infty}a_ib_i :a_1\in \mathfrak a,b_i\in\mathfrak b$}
.So my question is:why it was inserted $<\infty$?

Comment: It is to indicate that we are considering all possible finite combinations.

Comment: Infinite sums aren’t defined in a ring without additional structure to determine convergence

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949868/why-the-sum-of-the-product-of-ideals-are-defined-as-finite-sums-products), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220674/ideal-generated-by-union-of-ideals-contains-finite-sums-only). Before your next post (after 4 posts in 2 days), try to look a bit at this site first.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner very intersting.so it could be demonstrated that the product of two ideal have that form(without additional structure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groups, we would define product of two normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ something like $$H\cdot K =\{h\cdot k : h\in H, k\in K\}$$ However, there's a constraint in rings, we need ideals to be additive subgroups and in particular, closed under addition.

What more elements should we include in the set $P=\{ab:a\in \mathfrak a, b\in\mathfrak b\}$ so that it becomes closed under addition?

You need the additive subgroup spanned by elements of $P$.

Let me give an example to state what I mean. What's the additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ spanned by the set $\{1,\pi\}$? You must force it to be closed under addition $\{m+n\pi: m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

It was quite simple to find the additive span of two elements. What would be your approach for multiple elements or even possibly, infinitely many elements?

There can arbitrarily any number of elements in $P$. We pick finitely many elements from $P$ in all possible ways and take their sum.

$\mathfrak{a\cdot b}=\langle P\rangle_+ =\{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i:n\in\mathbb N, p_i\in P\}$

Now each $p_i=a_ib_i$ for some $a_i\in\mathfrak a$, $b_i\in\mathfrak b$.

This is the intuition behind why we need all possible finite sums. That $<\infty$ notation is used to indicate this fact only.

We can't have infinite sums because in an arbitrary ring, the concept of convergence is not defined.

---

Something I skipped in my explanation is that we needed negative integer multiples of $\pi$ and $1$ to find their additive span. Why don't we need the negatives in the finite sum for the product of ideals?

It is because $\{1,\pi\}$ was lacking in additive inverses, however, those ideals are additive subgroups, so for each $a\in\mathfrak a$, we must have the additive inverse $-a\in\mathfrak a$. Thus, there's no need to consider negative versions of the elements of the ideals in that finite sum.